# Required attribute for foreign keys

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm just thinking about a foreign key attribute in Entity Framework (using code first approach).
I want to ensure that this foreign key is always set, in other words: It should be required.

Is using the "Required"-attribute/data annotation a clean solution for this? Or should this data annotation be used for user input only?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think you need to have required attribute in the data annotation . If you have declared it as

```
public int ForeignKeyName{get;set;}
```

It will take as required by EF. And if it

```
 public int? ForeignKeyName{get;set;}
```

it will be taken as optional(nullable) by entity framework Conventions . I'm not sure what kind of framework you are using for the web(front end Ex: asp.net mvc). Depend on that you need to think about that input level.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. Thanks.
In other words I'll conecentrate on [Required] with strings only.

Comment: Sorry again. Are you sure about your statement? If I don't tell the model the id, wouldn't then the Id become 0?

Comment: Are you taking about the primaryKey here ? See the details of all conventions http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962

Comment: @mosquito87, Jayantha is correct, and regarding your question if you don't set the id yourself, your correct too, Entity Framework code first itself doesn't support this so you have to provide a navigation property along with the foreign key so Code First could fill in the id by itself. On the other hand Entity framework (not code first) supports this scenario by it self without the need for navigation property.